# How to update redux store in React regardless the cache

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have a server side render nodejs-react application that is creating the first store in Redux and save it as cache.

I need to overwrite one of that value when the user load my page, how can I do it?
Something like:

How it's working now

- server checks if there is a cache instance
- IF NOT: index.js > caching all the api/cms data in a store

What I need:
I need a case where whatever the cache instance is there or not, one property is always updated and not store in the case in redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch an action when the component gets mounted. Depending on whether you use hooks or classes you should do it in one of the following ways:

If you use hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {dispatch(your action, that changes the state)}, [])
```

If you use classes:

```
componendDidMount(){dispatch(your action, that changes the state)}
```